# ConcurrenthashMap and thread safety

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

javadocs of ConcurrenthashMap says:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access. **This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.**

What is the meaning of following statement from above paragraph?

> This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely
>   on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details

Answer (score 1):

`Hashtable` methods are `synchronized`, and you can write blocks of code being sure the state of the Hashtable won't change in the middle:

```
syncronized (hashtable) {
    if (!hashtable.contains(key))
        hashtable.put(key, value);
}
```

`ConcurrentHashMap`'s methods are not `synchronized` (though still thread-safe, as specified in the javadoc), you can't perform compound operations synchroniously with it's state.

<sup>Notice: the above example compound operation has a perfect equivalent in `ConcurrentHashMap` api: [`putIfAbsent(K, V)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K%2C%20V%29), but some other useful actions doesn't.</sup>

Comment: is the `you can't perform compound operations synchroniously with it's state` means that we cannot use above code with `synchronized(concurrenthashmap_obj)`?

Comment: @aLearner yes. Syntaxically you can, of cause, but it makes no sense for thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the javadocs for Hashtable:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the Map interface,        making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not
>   needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a
>   thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is
>   recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

I think they are saying that Hashtable has synchronized methods but the new ConcurrentHashMap doesn't use synchronization to ensure thread safety.   As for "interoperable", I think that means the interface is basically the same - so you can use either one.